# jqgrid, tooltip using table

Tags: jqgrid, tooltip

I have a jqgrid table and I'd like to allow users to click on an icon, invoke a URL and display the resultant data as a table inside a tool tip:

```
+-----------------------------+
| title1  | title2 | title 3| |
-----------------------------
| data1   |data 2 ? | data 3  |
+-----------------------------+
|data11   |data 21 ?| data 3  |
+----------------------------------+
           | child table           |
           +-----------------------+
           |                       |
           ------------------------+
```

In the above picture, the child table would be a tool tip